# Instagram real time API - getting empty data and no POST request in reply

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

There's been some thread regarding the [Instagram's realtime API](http://instagram.com/developer/clients/manage/?edited=MyHashtag), and it's remain unclear whether the fault is of Instagram or the developers that are trying to use it.

My issue is with the first subscription request. I think that my request is correct but I keep getting error \"callback_url\". URL must start with \"http://\" or \"https://\""

The request is:

```
curl -X POST 'httpiptions?client_id=CLIENT_ID&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET&object=tag&object_id=love&aspect=media&callback_url=http://myurl.com/subscribe'
```

Moreover, when I'm changing the request type to GET instead of POST I'm getting a successful message 200 with empty data, and Instagram do not invoke a POST request to my callback_url.

So as I see it there're 2 issues:
1) Should the request be POST( doesn't works for me) or GET( did work for me).
2) Why instagram returns empty data and do not POST to the callback_url.

Answer (score 0):

It has to be a POST.

In order to successfully subscribe and receive a response from the POST you do as your subscription request, your callback URL has to do some extra work and that is to also respond to a GET request sent from Instagram, right after you send the subscription request, to verify that you are the real owner of the callbalck URL.

In summary your callback URL, beside receiving POSTs, has to also respond to a GET request and echo back the `hub.challenge` parameter sent in that GET request.

Review the detailed description of the process in the documentation: http://instagram.com/developer/realtime/

**UPDATE:**

Now I could reproduce your described error.

The problem is with your CURL call. Your are supposed to send a POST request along with appropriate POST parameters but your call is doing a POST sending parameters as GET in the URL. Actually the API should reject the whole request but it seems it partially processes the parameters.

Change the CURL to:

```
curl -F 'client_id=CLIENT-ID' \
     -F 'client_secret=CLIENT-SECRET' \
     -F 'object=user' \
     -F 'aspect=media' \
     -F 'verify_token=myVerifyToken' \
     -F 'callback_url=http://YOUR-CALLBACK/URL' \
     https://api.instagram.com/v1/subscriptions/
```

This does a POST and sends your parameters correctly.

Comment: Thank you for the help, unfortunately I cannot get the first GET request with the hub.challenge because I keep getting the error message "callback_url\". URL must start with \"http://\" or \"https://\".